# GNU Make gcc, order of options

Tags: c, gcc, audio, makefile, static-libraries

I'm trying to figure out what way make is processing options on a gcc command:

I'm rebuilding one of Richard Dobson's programs to convert a soundfile to float,
and it requires linking a static library which is living in `$HOME/.local/lib`

the project builds no problem if I run
`gcc -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/.local/lib -lm -o sf2float sf2float.c -lportsf`

There are a couple of really useful posts elsewhere on stack exchange and also https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/06/19/

I'd really like to figure out how to run this command from within a makefile.

I've tried a few different variations of the following makefile:

```
SHELL=bash

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=$$HOME/.local/lib -lm -lportsf

OBJECTS = sf2float.o
BINARY = sf2float

all: sf2float

example: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(BINARY) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(BINARY) $(OBJECTS)
```

Which returns a slightly different variation of order of the compiler options, and then a bunch of errors after not finding the static library:

```
gcc -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/.local/lib -lm -lportsf  sf2float.o   -o sf2float
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.o: in function `main':
sf2float.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `psf_init'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `psf_sndOpen'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `psf_getFormatExt'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to `psf_sndCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `psf_sndReadFloatFrames'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `psf_sndWriteFloatFrames'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `psf_sndReadFloatFrames'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x2c7): undefined reference to `psf_sndReadPeaks'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `psf_sndClose'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x39f): undefined reference to `psf_sndClose'
/usr/bin/ld: sf2float.c:(.text+0x3ca): undefined reference to `psf_finish'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: sf2float] Error 1
```

It looks like I'm getting the order of the libraries a bit mixed up and to be honest, I'm just not totally sure what's going on here. The project is building as I mention above, but I'd like to understand the issue with make a bit more clearly moving forward. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Move `-o $(BINARY)` to the end in your `Example` target. You've got it before `$(LDFLAGS)` which is obviously not what works.

Comment: This comment is not right.  The order of `-o` is irrelevant.

Comment: etiquette here on SO is to always checkmark the best answer ... this give you the person asking some reputation points and gives some to the answerer plus it tells those watching from home which is the real answer ... welcome to SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems which are causing your issue.

The first one is a make problem: you have asked make to build `sf2float` because you have `all: sf2float` as your first target.

But, you haven't told make how to *build* `sf2float`.  You told it how to build a target called `example`, which you never listed as a prerequisite of anything:

```
example: $(OBJECTS)
```

So, make is not using your rule at all.  Luckily (?) make has built-in rules that know how to create a binary from an object file of the same name.  That built-in rule looks like this (basically):

```
% : %.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

That gives you the command line you see:

```
gcc -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/.local/lib -lm -lportsf  sf2float.o   -o sf2float
```

This gives you the errors you see because you have the libraries on the link line BEFORE the object file, and GCC like most linkers is a single-pass linker.

To fix this you should do one of two things (or maybe both):

By convention, the `LDFLAGS` make variable is used for linker *flags*, like `-Wl...`, and the `LDLIBS` make variable is used for libraries, like `-lm`.  So to follow convention, you would write:

```
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=$$HOME/.local/lib
LDLIBS = -lportsf -lm
```

And/or, if you want to use your rule instead of the built-in rule, you should change the target to be `sf2float` (or, use the `$(BINARY)` variable everywhere).

Comment: Hey, thanks a million - this really clarified things. I also went and had a quick look at the options section of the gcc manual this morning, so it helped me think a bit more clearly about what I was doing. The first thing I noticed was the failure to specify sf2float as a target as you correctly point out. Second thing was obviously the muddled LDFLAGS assignment. Thanks a lot for your answer, really clears things up!

Comment: If your question is answered please mark it that way, so that others will know.

Comment: aha, thanks - couldn't see the check mark initially!